# Anaconda won't open and all existing solutions don't work

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have tried everything. I installed Python 3.87 and Anaconda 3 on my Windows computer. It worked great yesterday but it won't open today.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling everything but still no luck. If I try to open anaconda, it looks like the program is starting to open but then it just stops and doesn't do anything. Tried running as administrator, tried adding all the correct paths to the environmental variables thing under system properties.

When I try "conda update conda" in the terminal, it just starts listing out what I had in my .py files from a crash course I was doing from my desktop folder. I don't understand how to fix this.

I am just trying to run Python with Spyder so I can learn basic coding.

```
C:\Users\Karmic Dreamwork.000>**conda update conda**
ctrl+enter runs script
You can add (+), subtract (-), multiply (*), and divide (/) integers in Python.
numbers with a decimal are called a 'float'

how to fix type errors
Happy 23rd Birthday!

python doesn't know whether you want 23 or 2 and 3, use the string function to fix this error
Happy 23rd Birthday!
use # for comments
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense.
Readability counts.
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
Now is better than never.
Although never is often better than *right* now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\KarmicDreamwork\Anaconda\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 12, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "D:\Users\KarmicDreamwork\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 149, in main
    from ..exceptions import conda_exception_handler
  File "D:\Users\KarmicDreamwork\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .common.io import dashlist, timeout
  File "D:\Users\KarmicDreamwork\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .._vendor.tqdm import tqdm
  File "D:\Users\KarmicDreamwork\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\tqdm\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ._tqdm import tqdm
  File "D:\Users\KarmicDreamwork\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\tqdm\_tqdm.py", line 18, in <module>
    from numbers import Number
ImportError: cannot import name 'Number' from 'numbers' (C:\Users\Karmic Dreamwork.000\Desktop\python_work\numbers.py)

C:\Users\Karmic Dreamwork.000>
```

Comment: I have met similar issue when I update conda. At that time, finally I need to re-install anaconda itself. That was 2-3 years ago so now I'm not sure but seeing github issues of conda might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove or rename this file

`C:\Users\Karmic Dreamwork.000\Desktop\python_work\numbers.py`

which is the one that's causing the error because it has the same name as the Python builtin module [`numbers`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/numbers.html).

Comment: You are a mad genius. IT WORKED!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! That's so strange because my book ( python crash course) told me to name it that.

Comment: Thanks! Please vote my answer as correct by clicking on the green check mark on the left.